# How to get all of the element ids on the same time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get all the `ids` names on a particular page and change it base on a particular name

Is it possible?

I tried so far:

```
function get_all()
{
    var esther = document.getElementById(*);
    document.getElementById("bod").value = esther;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change it base on a particular name"?

Comment: Even if that 1st line worked, the second one makes no sense. `esther` would be a `NodeList` containing all elements with an id, you'd have to iterate over them to look for a particular one. Please state exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: change the id name, lets say some of the id names are 1, I want to change all the id's which are 1 to another value

Comment: @ChrisG I want to display it on the screen

Comment: An `id` should always be unique, so if you have multiple elements with the same `id`, you already have a different problem. Having said that, your code isn't checking the id in any way. You have to iterate over the list of returned elements and actually compare the id (which is a string) to something else. I don't have the faintest idea what your goal is, sorry. I wish I could help you.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks but is it possible to change an id, would it affect the html element?

Comment: It's possible to change an id, yes. It will not affect the HTML element but if you have a CSS rule for the id, changing it to something else will remove the CSS styling. This seems more and more like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) though, can you tell us what the goal is here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203179/discussion-between-eyo-akak-and-chris-g).

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job

```
document.querySelectorAll('*[id]')
```

Comment: so how do i display it on the screen

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the list of `ids` on the page, you can grab all the elements on the page using:

```
let allElementsWithIds = [... document.querySelectorAll('[id]')];
```

And then you can create  a `<ul>` and populate it with the `ids` from each of those elements, before appending it to the document body.

***N.B.*** Note that `paragraph2` and `link1` in the example below **do not** have `ids`, so they do not appear in the list of ids.

**Working Example:**

```js
// Get all Elements with Ids
let allElementsWithIds = [... document.querySelectorAll('[id]')];

// Initialise List of Ids
let listOfIds = document.createElement('ul');
listOfIds.classList.add('top-right');

// Populate List of Ids
allElementsWithIds.forEach((element) => {

  let newListItem = document.createElement('li');
  newListItem.textContent = element.id;
  listOfIds.appendChild(newListItem);
});

// Append List Of Ids to Document Body
document.body.appendChild(listOfIds);
```

```css
.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  right: 24px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="heading1">This is Heading 1</h1>
<p id="paragraph1">This is Paragraph 1</p>
<p>This is Paragraph 2</p>
<p id="paragraph3">This is Paragraph 3</p>

<nav id="nav1">
<a href="link1">This is Link 1</a> |
<a id="link2" href="link2">This is Link 2</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log( getIds_1() );
console.log( getIds_2() );

function getIds_1(){
  let id = document.querySelectorAll('[id]');
  
  return [].slice.call(id).map(function(elem){
    return elem.id;
  }).join(", ");
}

function getIds_2(){
  return [...document.querySelectorAll('[id]')].map(e => e.id).join(", ");
}
```

```html
<div id="bubu"></div>
<div id="moo"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="example"></div>
<div id="id_007"></div>
```